# What are the benefits of investing in Design Guidelines (Design Language)?

Tags: guidelines, design-language

My company is questioning the need of establishing a common Design Language (guidelines, information architecture, visual design, etc). I have hard time conveying what is the value (business value) in investing in a design language.

What are the ROI benefits in creating a design language?

Comment: Consistency of product delivery and reduction in site refactoring and follow-up support work.  I am working on this exact thing to ensure that a team of developers testers and management all understand what we are working toward and how.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to promote the benefits of standardization as a process that

- enforces best practices (things like readability, coherence etc)
- saves organization time by preventing people from wasting time "being creative" when coming up with solutions to recurring problems (templates are key)
- sticking to the brand guidelines would ensure consistency, that drives trust in your business

Answer (score 0):

ROI benefits in this case would depend a lot on the size of the company and future growth. For a relatively small company where design team wouldn't grow rapidly or become disconnected over regions, design guidelines are 'preferred' or a 'good practice' not a 'necessity' from a revenue point of view. You can highlight the future growth of the company and then talk about all the valid points mentioned in previous answer by 321zeno (consistency, coherence, standardization, time efficiency, less confusion) to streamline design processes which would result in saving time and resources for the company.